# Error when trying to save to and read from the file JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have put together the following increment counter and have it running on a page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Click Counter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='inc/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentNumber = $('#currentNumber').text();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'increase_counter.php',
        data: {
counterId: event.target.id,
value: currentNumber
}
    })
    .done(function(newNumber){
        $('#currentNumber').text(newNumber);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="currentNumber">[xyz-ips snippet="Counter"]</div>
<button type="button" id="button 1">First Counter</button>
<button type="button" id="button 2">Second Counter</button>
</body>
</html>
```

With this PHP file:

```
<?php
$counters = json_decode($json);
if (isset($_POST['counterId'])) {
    $counterId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'counterId', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'value', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $counters[$counterId] = $value;
}
$json = json_encode($counters);
$counter_name = 'emailCounter.txt';

if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f,"0");
    fclose($f);
}

$counterVal = file_get_contents($counter_name);
$counterVal++;

$f = fopen($counter_name,"w");
fwrite($f, $counterVal);
fclose($f);

echo $counterVal;
?>
```

The idea being there are 2 or more independent counters on the page, that both work independently of each other, and the txt file generated on the server keeps tracks of the values. E.g.

> button 1: 4
>   button 2: 8

However, when I try to use it, I receive the following error:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: json in increase_counter.php on line 2"

I am very new to Javascript/PHP and have been working on it the past two days but have not been able to figure out how to make it work!
What's missing?

Comment: Well, just as the error msg says, look on line 2 of your PHP.  The error msg says the `$json` variable is undefined.  And looking at the code, nowhere before line 2 with `$counters = json_decode($json);` is the variable `$json` set to any value, so it is undefined ... but is still used in the call to `json_decode`.

Comment: Another user here gave me that JSON snippet and said "Save to and read from the file that JSON string." - I have literally never used JSON before, but i assumed he got it right haha. How could the $json be set to a value if the value is always changing with each click?

Comment: The code you have is not really using `$json` at all.  On line 8 you set it with `$json = json_encode($counters);`.  But you never use `$json` after you set it.  In answer below, I've given example of how you can save all ounters in JSON format into a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's code uses `$json` (line 2) before setting it then sets `$json` (line 8) but never uses it.  Below is sample code that'll save all counters in a single file.  The counters are stored in JSON format in the file.

```
$countersFile = 'emailCounter.txt';

if ( isset($_POST['counterId']) ) {
    $counterId = $_POST['counterId'];

    if ( !file_exists($countersFile) ) {
        $counters = [];
    } else {
        $counters = json_decode(file_get_contents($countersFile), TRUE);
        if ( is_null($counters) ) $counters = [];
    }

    if ( array_key_exists($counterId, $counters) ) {
        $counters[$counterId]++;
    } else {
        $counters[$counterId] = 1;
    }

    file_put_contents($countersFile,
        json_encode($counters, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
        LOCK_EX);

    echo $counters[$counterId];
}
```

EDIT:  Added TRUE to `json_decode` (I always seem to forget that :( ) and checked for null/bad-json.

Comment: Oh wow! It worked for 1 until I got this error/s: "PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /public_html/second-test/increase_counter.php on line 13
 PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /public_html/second-test/increase_counter.php on line 16
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /public_html/second-test/increase_counter.php on line 14

Comment: My code assumed if the file exists, it would contain the JSON representation of an array written in an earlier request.  Could you retry but this time don't use the same `emailCounter.txt` file used by your code (either delete or rename it).

Comment: yup, deleted the old file. It generated a new one, then increased by one, but it wouldn't increase any further giving the following: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in public_html/second-test/increase_counter.php on line 16"

Comment: The new emailCounter.txt generated generated by your code says { "Button 1": 1 }, but won't increase past that

Comment: Yes, me bad.  `json_decode` needs a TRUE for it to return assoc-arrays instead of StdClass.  Apologies; fixed above.

Comment: YOU LEGEND! Amazing! Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add in you code php this:

```
<?php
$json = '';
if (file_exists('emailCounter.txt') {
  $json = file_get_contents('emailCounter.txt');
}
$counters = json_decode($json); // your old line 2
// ... 
?>
```

On html i suggest you change the id elements to button_1 and button_2, like:

```
<button type="button" id="button_1">First Counter</button>
<button type="button" id="button_2">Second Counter</button>
```